# Python Pandas: How to groupby and count and select a portion of counts?

Tags: python, pandas, count, group-by

I have a df like this:

```
          new_org               old_org    asn  cc
0    85736 pcizzi   85736 - Pcizzi S .a  23201  PY
1             001              001 Host  40244  US
2      85736 blah       85736 - whatevs  23201  PY
3             001        001 IT Complex  55734  IN
4  001 hospedagem   001 Hospedagem Ltda  36351  US
5          001web  action.us.001web.net  36351  US
```

and I would like to groupby my df based on 'asn' column and select those groups which have more than one row. This is how I am doing it now but I am not sure if it is correct:

```
df.groupby('asn').apply(lambda x:x.count()>1)
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [filter a group](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration).

Try `df.groupby('asn').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)` which will return you a `DataFrame`. You could group it again further if necessary.